# Spring Cloud CLI could not find artifact

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, spring-cloud

I follow guide at https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-cli/docs/current/reference/html/#_running_spring_cloud_services_in_development . My command

```
spring cloud eureka configserver h2 kafka stubrunner zipkin
```

```
C:\Users\Administrator>spring --version
Spring CLI v2.6.6
C:\Users\Administrator>spring cloud --list
'cloud' is not a valid command. See 'help'.

C:\Users\Administrator>spring cloud eureka configserver h2 kafka stubrunner zipkin
'cloud' is not a valid command. See 'help'.

C:\Users\Administrator>spring-cloud
'spring-cloud' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\Administrator>spring cloud eureka configserver h2 kafka stubrunner zipkin

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.4.3)

2022-04-05 10:13:24.350  INFO 10488 --- [           main] o.s.c.l.deployer.DeployerApplication     : Starting DeployerApplication v3.0.2 using Java 11.0.12 on 21AK22-COM with PID 10488 (C:\Users\Administrator\.m2\repository\org\springframework\cloud\launcher\spring-cloud-launcher-deployer\3.0.2\spring-cloud-launcher-deployer-3.0.2.jar started by Administrator in C:\Users\Administrator)
2022-04-05 10:13:24.354  INFO 10488 --- [           main] o.s.c.l.deployer.DeployerApplication     : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2022-04-05 10:13:24.405  WARN 10488 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.config.ConfigDataEnvironment     : Property 'spring.profiles' imported from location 'class path resource [cloud.yml]' is invalid and should be replaced with 'spring.config.activate.on-profile' [origin: class path resource [cloud.yml] from spring-cloud-launcher-deployer-3.0.2.jar - 97:13]
2022-04-05 10:13:24.901  INFO 10488 --- [           main] o.s.c.l.deployer.DeployerApplication     : Started DeployerApplication in 0.947 seconds (JVM running for 3.562)
[main] ERROR org.springframework.cloud.launcher.cli.LauncherCommand - Error running spring cloud
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.springframework.cloud.launcher.cli.LauncherCommand$LauncherOptionHandler.run(LauncherCommand.java:115)
        at org.springframework.boot.cli.command.options.OptionHandler.run(OptionHandler.java:105)
        at org.springframework.boot.cli.command.OptionParsingCommand.run(OptionParsingCommand.java:54)
        at org.springframework.boot.cli.command.CommandRunner.run(CommandRunner.java:219)
        at org.springframework.boot.cli.command.CommandRunner.runAndHandleErrors(CommandRunner.java:171)
        at org.springframework.boot.cli.SpringCli.main(SpringCli.java:64)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.wrapper.ThinJarWrapper.launch(ThinJarWrapper.java:139)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.wrapper.ThinJarWrapper.main(ThinJarWrapper.java:107)
        ... 18 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.thin.ThinJarLauncher.launch(ThinJarLauncher.java:187)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.thin.ThinJarLauncher.main(ThinJarLauncher.java:140)
        ... 24 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to resolve MavenResource: org.springframework.cloud.launcher:spring-cloud-launcher-kafka:jar:3.0.2. Configured remote repositories: central,spring-milestone,spring-snapshot
        at org.springframework.cloud.deployer.resource.maven.MavenArtifactResolver.resolve(MavenArtifactResolver.java:287)
        at org.springframework.cloud.deployer.resource.maven.MavenResource.getFile(MavenResource.java:169)
        at org.springframework.cloud.deployer.thin.ThinJarAppWrapper.<init>(ThinJarAppWrapper.java:74)
        at org.springframework.cloud.deployer.thin.AbstractThinJarSupport.deploy(AbstractThinJarSupport.java:52)
        at org.springframework.cloud.deployer.thin.ThinJarAppDeployer.deploy(ThinJarAppDeployer.java:63)
        at org.springframework.cloud.launcher.deployer.Deployer.deployInternal(Deployer.java:203)
        at org.springframework.cloud.launcher.deployer.Deployer.deploy(Deployer.java:108)
        at org.springframework.cloud.launcher.deployer.DeployerApplication.launch(DeployerApplication.java:140)
        at org.springframework.cloud.launcher.deployer.DeployerApplication.run(DeployerApplication.java:68)
        at org.springframework.cloud.launcher.deployer.DeployerApplication.main(DeployerApplication.java:58)
        ... 33 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not find artifact org.springframework.cloud.launcher:spring-cloud-launcher-kafka:jar:3.0.2 in central (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:444)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:246)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveArtifacts(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:302)
        at org.springframework.cloud.deployer.resource.maven.MavenArtifactResolver.resolve(MavenArtifactResolver.java:272)
        ... 42 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactNotFoundException: Could not find artifact org.springframework.cloud.launcher:spring-cloud-launcher-kafka:jar:3.0.2 in central (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2)
        at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.ArtifactTransportListener.transferFailed(ArtifactTransportListener.java:39)
        at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$TaskRunner.run(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:355)
        at org.eclipse.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run(RunnableErrorForwarder.java:67)
        at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$DirectExecutor.execute(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:581)
        at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector.get(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:249)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:520)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:421)
        ... 45 more
C:\Users\Administrator>spring cloud eureka configserver h2 kafka stubrunner zipkin
```

[image]

[image]

How to fix it?

Comment: he, Kafka and zipkin are no longer available. The docs need to be fixed

Answer (score 0):

Hello it seems cli trying to fetch dependency from maven which does not exists.

Ref:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud.launcher/spring-cloud-launcher-kafka

There is no version named 3.0.2 in repository, so it fails to resolve.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check the Spring cloud plugin installation was completed and compare the following steps.
   mvn install -> needs more elaboration
   Refer as below

   git clone https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-cli.git
   cd spring-cloud-cli
   mvn install
2. Once above is completed check the summary, this has missing kafka installation
   [image]
3. check the directory ../spring-cloud-cli/spring-cloud-launcher
   and open pom.xml
   [image]
4. if kafka module is commented as above that means kafka installation is not completed